# Find Total Mass of a Solid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help finding total mass of a solid. So this solid is defined by inequalities:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1, x\ge 0, y\ge 0$$
and has a mass density of $z^2$.

Maybe we can convert this to cylindrical. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: can you find a parametrization of the solid?

Comment: @Surb No, I'm not sure how to do it in this case?

Comment: ok. Do you know what does the volume $\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$ represent?

Comment: @surb. Yes it's the volume of a sphere.

Comment: actually it is the unit ball :) (the sphere is for $x^2+y^2+z^2{\color{red}=}1$), and do you know how to parametrize this unit ball? have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: $x = rsinφcosθ, x = rsinφsinθ, z = rcosφ, 0≤θ<2π, 0≤φ≤π$?

Comment: exactly :). You will also need $0\leq r \leq 1$. Now, you have to restrict the intervals $0\leq \theta <2\pi$ and $0\leq \varphi \leq \pi$ in order to guarantee $x\geq 0 $ and $y\geq 0 $

Comment: @Surb Can you please set it up for me?

Comment: I'm sure you can make it by yourself. Look at [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#/media/File:3D_Spherical_2.svg) and try to guess

Comment: Does the final answer come out to $(1/4)\pi^2K$?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer. However, you should find these bounds for $\theta$ and $\varphi$, then make the variable change in your triple integral (don't forget the determinant of the Jacobian) and integrate over $r,\theta,\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $E$ denote the region of interest.  Then the total mass of $E$ is $\iiint_E z^2\text{d}V$.  Since $E$ is part of a ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin, it is best to use spherical coordinates.

Comment: Okay. So now how do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Mass}=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\int_0^1r^2\cos^2\phi ~r^2\sin\phi \,dr\,d\phi\, d\theta$$